categorical interpretation of characterization of map of sets factoring through
Let $f: X \to Z$ be a map (of sets) and suppose $g: X \to Y$ is another map. Also let $X_f$ be the partition of $X$ induced by $f$, i.e. the partition induced by the relation $x \sim y \iff f(x) = f(y)$. Then I am pretty sure it is the case that that $f$ factors through $g$, i.e. that there exists a map $h: Y \to Z$ such that $f = h \circ g$, if and only if $X_g$ is a refinement of $X_f$, i.e. for every $[x] \in X_g$ there is a $[y] \in X_f$ such that $[x] \subset [y]$. Moreover, this map is unique on $\operatorname{im}(g)$ iff $X_f = X_g$.
Now my question is, do the above properties imply anything special about the category $\mathbf{Set}$? Maybe it is just a simple categorical reformulation? The setup reminded me somewhat of equalizers, though it is not exactly the same.

Check out the idea of the coimage of  a morphism. The quotient $X/{\sim}$ is the coimage of $f$.

This is a great answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@Martin it took me a long time but there it is. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Check out the idea of the coimage of a morphism. The quotient $X\to X/{∼}$ is the coimage of $f$. In other words, $f$ factors through the projection $X\to X/{\sim}$ and this projection is the best (initial) map out of $X$ through which $f$ factors.
